# How to pass a $ object from an array to a view?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct MyObject: Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id: UUID = UUID()
  var name, brand: String
  init(name: String = "", brand: String = "") {
    self.name = varName
    self.brand = brand
  }
}

final class Model:ObservableObject {
  @Published var objects = (0..<3).compactMap {_ in
    return MyObject()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  private let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
  @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      LazyVGrid(
        columns: columns,
        alignment: .center,
        spacing: 10,
        pinnedViews: []
      ) {
        ForEach($model.objects, id:\.id) {$object in
          TextField(object.name,
                    text: $object.name,
                    prompt: Text("name"))
          
          TextField(object.brand,
                    text: $object.brand,
                    prompt: Text("brand"))
        }
      }
      
    }
    .padding(20)
  }
}
```

As you can see, this `ForEach` is using Binding elements to the array, so any change to a textfield will update the array.

Now I want to condense this part

```
TextField(object.name,
          text: $object.name,
          prompt: Text("name"))
      
TextField(object.brand,
          text: $object.brand,
          prompt: Text("brand"))
```

into a view.

I have tried everything but I cannot realize how I should pass these elements to a view and how do I initialize them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean extracting the text field into a separate view?

You need a constant for the prompt and a `@Binding` for the text.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            LazyVGrid(
                columns: columns,
                alignment: .center,
                spacing: 10,
                pinnedViews: []
            ) {
                ForEach($model.objects, id:\.id) {$object in
                    TextFieldView(prompt: "name", text: $object.name)
                    TextFieldView(prompt: "brand", text: $object.brand)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct TextFieldView : View {
    let prompt: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(text,
                  text: $text,
                  prompt: Text(prompt))
    }
}
```